# How can I make R able to compute a formula based on the cell address in a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a generic formula that has to be applied on each cell of a matrix.

```
Sij = Nij / sqrt(Ni*Nj)
```

Ni and Nj are already defined in vector "count" as (A,B,C,D,E). You can think of them as Na,Nb,Nc,Nd,Ne; these values will go in the denominator.

Nij are defined in matrix "mat_ans_2". You can think of them as Nab, Nac, Nad and so on; these values will go in the numerator.

From this, I want to generate a new matrix that has all the Sij computations. It will look as follows:

```
     A      B     C     D     E
 A   1    0.4842

 B  0.4842  1 

 C                1

 D                      1

 E                            1
```

Diagonal will be set to 1 as default. The value that goes into AB is derived from this formula:

```
Sab = Nab/sqrt(Na*Nb) = 0.4842
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been so lucky in generating a "for" function.

```
Cij = mat_ans_2
diag(Cij) <- 1
Si = count
Sj = count
Si <- matrix(Si, nrow = length(Si), ncol = length(Si), byrow = TRUE)
Sj <- matrix(Sj, nrow = length(Sj), ncol = length(Sj), byrow = FALSE)
for (i,j in count) { 
   SC <- (Cij)/sqrt(Si * Sj)
       SC[is.na(SC)] <- 0
       diag(SC) <- 1
       return(SC)
   }
```

What is the best way to make R able to recognize each address and perform the formula accordingly?

```
dput(mat_ans_2)
structure(c(1, 1.21666666666667, 0.55, 0.15, 0, 1.21666666666667, 
1, 1.81666666666667, 0.75, 0.35, 0.55, 1.81666666666667, 1, 1.98333333333333, 
0.533333333333333, 0.15, 0.75, 1.98333333333333, 1, 2.7, 0, 0.35, 
0.533333333333333, 2.7, 1), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")))

dput(count)
structure(list(class = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), `sum(weight, na.rm = TRUE)` = c(1.59166666666667, 
3.96666666666667, 3.29166666666667, 3.35833333333333, 3.29166666666667
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001e7d1611ef0>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Bottom-Line Up-Front

```r
mat_ans_2 / sqrt(outer(count[[2]], count[[2]], `*`))
```

---

### Explanation / Walk-Through

Looking at just your denominator, that looks to me to be an outer-product, for which there is good support:

```r
outer(count[[2]], count[[2]])
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
# [1,] 2.533403  6.313611  5.239236  5.345347  5.239236
# [2,] 6.313611 15.734444 13.056944 13.321389 13.056944
# [3,] 5.239236 13.056944 10.835069 11.054514 10.835069
# [4,] 5.345347 13.321389 11.054514 11.278403 11.054514
# [5,] 5.239236 13.056944 10.835069 11.054514 10.835069
```

This takes each of `count[[2]]` and does a cartesian expansion of it, executing a particular function. The default is the product, but you can also specify it manually/explicitly with:

```r
outer(count[[2]], count[[2]], `*`)
```

Internally, this just produces two vectors, each of length `length(count[[2]])^2`:

```r
outer(count[[2]], count[[2]], function(a, b) { browser(); a*b; })
# Called from: FUN(X, Y, ...)
# Browse[1]> 
debug at #1: a * b
# Browse[2]> 
a
#  [1] 1.591667 3.966667 3.291667 3.358333 3.291667 1.591667 3.966667 3.291667
#  [9] 3.358333 3.291667 1.591667 3.966667 3.291667 3.358333 3.291667 1.591667
# [17] 3.966667 3.291667 3.358333 3.291667 1.591667 3.966667 3.291667 3.358333
# [25] 3.291667
# Browse[2]> 
cbind(a,b)
#              a        b
#  [1,] 1.591667 1.591667
#  [2,] 3.966667 1.591667
#  [3,] 3.291667 1.591667
#  [4,] 3.358333 1.591667
#  [5,] 3.291667 1.591667
#  [6,] 1.591667 3.966667
#  [7,] 3.966667 3.966667
#  [8,] 3.291667 3.966667
#  [9,] 3.358333 3.966667
# [10,] 3.291667 3.966667
# [11,] 1.591667 3.291667
# [12,] 3.966667 3.291667
# [13,] 3.291667 3.291667
# [14,] 3.358333 3.291667
# [15,] 3.291667 3.291667
# [16,] 1.591667 3.358333
# [17,] 3.966667 3.358333
# [18,] 3.291667 3.358333
# [19,] 3.358333 3.358333
# [20,] 3.291667 3.358333
# [21,] 1.591667 3.291667
# [22,] 3.966667 3.291667
# [23,] 3.291667 3.291667
# [24,] 3.358333 3.291667
# [25,] 3.291667 3.291667
```

From here, it's easy enough to finish the denominator with

```r
sqrt(outer(count[[2]], count[[2]], `*`))
```

Since the numerator is already a matrix of the same dimensions, it's just a simple division:

```r
out <- mat_ans_2 / sqrt(outer(count[[2]], count[[2]], `*`))
out
#            A          B         C          D          E
# A 0.62827225 0.48420882 0.2402861 0.06487887 0.00000000
# B 0.48420882 0.25210084 0.5027528 0.20548802 0.09686062
# C 0.24028613 0.50275277 0.3037975 0.59652120 0.16202532
# D 0.06487887 0.20548802 0.5965212 0.29776675 0.81207088
# E 0.00000000 0.09686062 0.1620253 0.81207088 0.30379747
```

Since you said you needed the diagonal to be all 1s, then

```r
diag(out) <- 1
out
#            A          B         C          D          E
# A 1.00000000 0.48420882 0.2402861 0.06487887 0.00000000
# B 0.48420882 1.00000000 0.5027528 0.20548802 0.09686062
# C 0.24028613 0.50275277 1.0000000 0.59652120 0.16202532
# D 0.06487887 0.20548802 0.5965212 1.00000000 0.81207088
# E 0.00000000 0.09686062 0.1620253 0.81207088 1.00000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggest, @akrun.